# $(document).height() randomizes value on refresh (Safari 5.1.10)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I use `$(document).height()` to set the `height` CSS property on a block. It's a workaround for Safari 5.1.10 (OSX 10.6.8) as the `vh` unit (*viewport height*) don't work on this version.

```
(function() {
    if(!Modernizr.cssvhunit) $("#sidebar").css("height", $(document).height()+"px");
})();
```

The problem is that the value returned by `$(document).height()` is **not the same everytime I refresh** the page. Sometimes it's the **viewport** height, sometimes the **document** height, sometimes a value between the two...

I use: *Modernizr 2.8.3* to detect the `vh` unit support, *jQuery 1.11.0*, *Lightbox 2.7.1* (problem still occurs without it) and *Skeleton 2.0.4*.

I also tried this workaround but it didn't work:

```
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
}
```

I have no idea what would cause this supposed constant value to be variable...

Comment: It sounds like you may be getting the height whilst the images in the page are still loading, hence the page is still expanding. Try getting the height under the `$(window).load(fn)` event instead, as all imagery should be loaded at that point.

Comment: That made it, thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped - I added it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be getting the height whilst the images in the page are still loading, hence the page is still expanding.

In this case, try getting the height under the `$(window).load(fn)` event instead, as all imagery should be loaded at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to measure height and width *after a while*.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // get w, h
},1);
```

Explanation: JS-in-the-browser is an evend-based front-end system. The following steps repeat:

1. receive user/timeout/AJAX event
2. run JavaScript listeners (if any)
3. re-render the DOM changes

Page rendering happens at #3, but your JS code runs in #2, *before* final/proper sizes determined for display elements. Setting a very short timeout in #2 will occur to re-run the 3-step cycle, when the #3 is already finished.

That's why there's no effect, when you hide an element, then show it, and repeat it even 100 times: no rendering hapens during #2, and if you leave it shown, #3 will found no change, nothing happens.

Well, it is not too elegant, and requires extra effort to write a UI program, which can't get the dimensions when it needed.

Comment: It worked with a timeout, but binding the CSS modification to the `$(window).load()` event is more precise.

Comment: Fyeah, image loading! You may specify your `img` sizes in HTML/CSS... if you know it.